# Compute $ f(x) = \int_0^{\pi} \frac{ \sin \theta ( \cos \theta - x) d \theta}{ [(\cos \theta - x)^2 + \sin^2 \theta]^{1.5} } x \in \Bbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Compute

$$ f(x) = \int_0^{\pi} \frac{ \sin \theta ( \cos \theta - x)}{ [(\cos \theta - x)^2 + \sin^2 \theta]^{1.5} }
\,\,d \theta\,,\quad   x \in \Bbb{R}$$

The denominator makes it a bit annoying. We can evaluate it as

$ [(\cos \theta - x)^2 + \sin^2 \theta = (1 - 2 \cos \theta x + x^2)^{1.5}$ but it doesn't make it any easier.  We can also expand $(1 + x^2 - 2 \cos \theta x )^{1.5}$ using $(1+x)^\alpha = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{n} x^n$ but it's still difficult.

The denominator also has some geometric meaning  (cubed distance from $(x,0)$ to $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ ) but does it help?

Comment: Maybe the substitution $\cos\theta=x+t$ will works.

Comment: Where did you find this integral? Some information about what this is related to might help finding a solution. On its own it is very bothersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $r = r(\theta) = \sqrt{1 - 2x\cos\theta + x^2}$. Then we easily check that

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d} r^{\alpha}}{\mathrm{d}\theta} = \alpha r^{\alpha-2} x\sin\theta, \qquad\text{and so},\qquad \int r^{\beta}\sin\theta \, \mathrm{d}\theta = \frac{r^{\beta+2}}{(\beta+2)x}. $$

Now denoting the integral by $f(x)$ and assuming that $x \neq \pm 1$, we have

\begin{align*}
f(x)
&= \int_{0}^{\pi} r^{-3}\sin\theta(\cos\theta - x) \, \mathrm{d}\theta \\
&= \left[ - \frac{r^{-1}(\cos\theta - x)}{x} \right]_{0}^{\pi} - \frac{1}{x} \int_{0}^{\pi} r^{-1}\sin\theta \, \mathrm{d}\theta \\
&= \frac{1}{x}\left( \frac{1-x}{r(0)} + \frac{1+x}{r(\pi)} \right) - \left[ \frac{r}{x^2} \right]_{0}^{\pi}.
\end{align*}

By using $r(\pi) = \left| 1 + x \right|$ and $r(0) = \left| 1 - x \right|$, we get

\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \frac{\operatorname{sgn}(1+x) + \operatorname{sgn}(1-x)}{x} - \frac{\left| 1 + x\right| - \left|1 - x \right|}{x^2} \\
&= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left( \frac{\left| 1 + x\right| - \left|1 - x \right|}{x} \right).
\end{align*}

Noting that

$$ \frac{\left| 1 + x\right| - \left|1 - x \right|}{x} = \begin{cases}
2/x, & x > 1, \\
2, & -1 < x < 1, \\
-2/x, & x < -1,
\end{cases} $$

it follows that

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
-2/x^2, & x > 1, \\
0, & -1 < x < 1, \\
2/x^2, & x < -1.
\end{cases} $$

Given this form, I suspect that $f$ comes from an electromagnetism problem of computing the electric field arising from a charged metal sphere or something like that.

---

*Remark.* It can be checked separately that

$$ f(1)
= -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\sin\theta}{\sqrt{1-\cos\theta}} \, \mathrm{d}\theta
= -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \left[ \sqrt{1-\cos\theta} \right]_{0}^{\pi}
= -1 $$

and

$$ f(-1)
= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\sin\theta}{\sqrt{1+\cos\theta}} \, \mathrm{d}\theta
= -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \left[ \sqrt{1+\cos\theta} \right]_{0}^{\pi}
= 1. $$

Therefore the complete answer is as follows:

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
-\frac{2}{x^2}, & x \in (1, \infty), \\
-1, & x = 1, \\
0, & x \in (-1, 1), \\
1, & x = -1, \\
\frac{2}{x^2}, & x \in (-\infty, -1).
\end{cases} $$

Comment: interesting, why can't $x$ be $1$ or $-1$?

Comment: @JoshBolton, In fact, $x$ can be either $1$ or $-1$ as well. The singularity of the integrand of $I$ does not impede us from computing $I$. And it turns out that the value of $I=I(x)$ at $x=\pm1$ is precisely the average of the left-side limit and right-side limit of $I$ at $x$. Which can of course be directly deduced from the first formula for $I$.

Comment: But what should the value be at $f(1)$ or $f(-1)$. It's not continuous there..

Comment: @JoshBolton, I added the computation to my answer. Mathematically, it is quite possible that a seeming innocuous integral exhibits discontinuities, and that often admits an explanation based on complex analysis (as the contour of integration crosses the singularity of the integrand or something like that). How this should be interpreted in the context where the integral arises, I am not sure.

Comment: Thank you. Do you mind explaining why you think this problem has something to do with "an electromagnetism problem of computing the electric field arising from a charged metal sphere"? I found this on a calculus exercise book with no background given, but I am interested in learning potential use case

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sequence of substitutions:

$$u=\cos\theta-x\implies\mathrm du=-\sin\theta\,\mathrm d\theta$$

$$\implies f(x)=-\int_{1-x}^{-1-x}\frac u{(u^2+1-(u+x)^2)^{\frac32}}\,\mathrm du=\int_{-1-x}^{1-x}\frac u{(1-2ux-x^2)^{\frac32}}\,\mathrm du$$

Then

$$v=1-2ux-x^2\implies\mathrm dv=-2\,\mathrm du$$

$$\implies f(x)=\frac1{4x}\int_{x^2+2x+1}^{-3x^2+2x+1}\frac{v+x^2-1}{v^{\frac32}}\,\mathrm dv$$

Comment: It seems like $\int \frac{v+x^2-1}{v^{3/2}} dv = \frac{2(v-x^2+1)}{\sqrt{v}}$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct